# Get access token

Tags: angular, api, access-token

In my app I want to take access token for authorization purpose. When user log in to the system it generate tokens as below.

> {
> "email": "test@gmail.com",
> "tokens": "{'refresh': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYxMzcwMzg2OSwianRpIjoiZmQ1MjU5ODVmNjMwNGI1NWFiNjJiNGVmYmNhMGUyNTMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.OAR-aUstvgPz8Yue7Zo8OFQyjvwCFK8_a5n84cPqLCs', 'access': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjEyNjY3MDY5LCJqdGkiOiJlMGZkZmUyNWI0OWI0ZDdmODJkYWE4YTJhZWUwYjdmZCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.TKw15NmLbSdIRwXWiu6UiMIudaCe5ecqyANNvA7YLQg'}"
> }

It has both access and refresh tokens. But I just need access token for authorization purpose. How can I take just access token.

Comment: In which object you are storing these all tokens?

Comment: I don't see any curly braces outside tokens

Comment: @Jay I store token as this.             
  "localStorage.setItem("userTokens",results.tokens)"

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly a json object, so if you object is like obj where you are getting this response from the server. You should do below to get access:

```
obj.tokens.access
```

This should work.